# refrence error "'name of array in state' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I cannot seem to set the state of a property in my array because react thinks it is undefined, or I guess it clearly is undefined, would anyone be able to tell me what Is wrong with my code!

**State in constructor**

```
constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                listOfItems: [],
                listOfEquiptment: [],
                listOfSpells: [],
                choosableEquiptment:[],
                choosableSpells: [],
                currentEquiptment: undefined,
                currentSpell: undefined
            }
            this.addNewEquiptment =this.addNewEquiptment.bind(this);
            this.addNewSpell =this.addNewSpell.bind(this);
            this.handleEquiptmentChange = this.handleEquiptmentChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSpellChange = this.handleSpellChange.bind(this);
    }
```

**property i'm trying to reassign **

```
if(prevProps.chosenCharacter != this.props.chosenCharacter){
            axios.get(`/api/${this.props.chosenUser.name}/characters/${this.props.chosenCharacter.name}`)
            .then(results =>{
                let newArr = results.data;
                // newArr.sort((a, b) => {
                //     return (a.item > b.item ? 1 : -1)
                // })
                console.log("arr after sort is", newArr)
                this.setState({
                    listOfItems: newArr
                });
                console.log('list of items after set state ', listOfItems)
                .then(results =>{
                    const tempEquipArr = [];
                    const tempSpellArr = [];
                    for(const item of listOfItems){
                        (item.type == "spell")? tempSpellArr.push(item.name) : tempEquipArr.push(item.name);
                    }
                })
                this.setState({
                    listOfEquiptment: tempEquipArr,
                    listOfSpells:tempSpellArr
                })
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                console.error(err);
            })  
        }
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of your component code?

Comment: How do you know that it is undefined? React setState is asynchronous, so if you're console.logging right after, it's gonna show undefined.

Comment: sorry! i updated the code to show more, I wasn't sure it was relevant

Comment: i know its undefined because the app crashes and does not get to the next console.log

Comment: it also gives me the error saying that it is undefined

Comment: Few problems here. First, `setState` is asynchronous as @alex067 said, so you can't log it on the next line and expect it to change. You'd need to use `setState`'s second argument, a callback done after the state changes. Second, you're logging `listOfItems` which is the name of the _key_. You should be logging `this.state. listOfItems`. Third, `setState` isn't a promise, so you can't use `.then` on it. And even if you could, you plopped a `console.log` in the way. Fourth, `const` is scoped, so you wouldn't be able to access it in the subsequent `setState` anyway

Comment: And that's not even all the issues with this code. I think you need a better understand of how asynchronous code works in JS, particularly `setState` and Promises. Also, look into scoping of `let/const` vs `var`. Even if someone cleaned this code up for you, if you don't understand those principles you'll face similar issues again pretty soon

Comment: Thankyou, I am learning, I thought I Was using everything properly, I thought i was setting the state in the promise, not chaining it as part of the promise chain. I really do appreciate the feedback though, I am definetly struggling understanding how to deal with asynchronus programming

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problems in your code is with the setState function. You shouldn't be using `.then()` as a follow up to `this.setState()` as it's not a promise. Instead, you can use the [built in callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

In this way, your `setState` will look like this:

```
this.setState({listOfItems: newArr}, () => {
   console.log('list of items after set state ', listOfItems)
   ///Do whatever you need to after the state change
})
```